# Mapping more strings to one value

Tags: java, constructor, hashmap

I have a constructor that maps the first letter of the words in a text file to all the words that start with that letter and are longer than 3 characters

```
 protected WordStore(String file){
    try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(file))) {
         this.bigMap = br.lines().filter(line -> line.length() > 3).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.substring(0, 1)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

While reading the file, the constructor should then for each word add mappings for all applicable prefixes up to that length.
For instance, for a prefix length of 3 and the word “abacus”, 
the mappings:

- a -> abacus
- ab -> abacus
- aba -> abacus

Should be added.

Also words shorter than or of equal length to the prefix length should be ignored.

How would you change the constructor I already have so that it accomplishes this task? I'm pretty sure I should add another argument to the constructor that loads a dictionary for the maximum prefix length but I am stuck.

Comment: Add the format of your textfile to the question, it seems relevant. Instead of using a Collectors, consider map() or forEach() to insert into a map that you create manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
    List<String> testList = Arrays.asList("abckddkd", "abdsdfwer", "acdxdf");
    Map<String, List<String>> resultMap = testList.stream().filter(line -> line.length() > 3)
            .collect(Collector.of(HashMap::new, (map, line) -> {
                IntStream.range(1, 4).forEach(n->{
                    if(map.get(line.substring(0, n))==null) {
                        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                        list.add(line);
                        map.put(line.substring(0, n),list);
                    }else {
                        //handle duplicate here if you want
                        map.get(line.substring(0, n)).add(line);
                    }
                });
            }, (map1, map2) -> {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }, new Characteristics[] { Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH }));
    System.out.println(resultMap);
```

output:

> {a=[abckddkd, abdsdfwer, acdxdf], ab=[abckddkd, abdsdfwer], abd=[abdsdfwer], ac=[acdxdf], abc=[abckddkd], acd=[acdxdf]}